# Figuring out an outage based on splunk logs

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, error-handling, splunk

I'm trying to figure out a way where, when there are n number of failures of a particular service based on the splunk logs, I'd like to send in the response of that service going forward for all the calls made that there is an outage.

For example, xyz.com/support is a service that is failing for more than 300 times in an hour, splunk will send me an email saying there are so many failures for this service, now based on this I'd like to modify my response to something like below response until the outage is resolved. This should be automated.

{"status":"failure","level":"","message":"There is an outage currently"}

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can store the count of failures and when it reaches the threshold you can send the desired error message. You can reset the count based on your requirement.